Cannot find and allocate disk space
I'm having a problem with some space assigned to a server, I need to add 1TB to the partition /store
df -h shows
[root@SERVER ~]# df -h
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                           12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              12G   56K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              12G   26M   12G   1% /run
tmpfs                              12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-root          13G  3.5G  9.1G  28% /
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-opt           13G  6.6G  6.0G  53% /opt
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-storetmp      15G   34M   15G   1% /storetmp
/dev/mapper/storerhel-store       2.9T  2.6T  350G  89% /store
/dev/sda3                          32G  5.5G   27G  18% /recovery
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-tmp          3.0G   46M  3.0G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-var          5.0G  253M  4.8G   5% /var
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-varlog        15G  1.3G   14G   9% /var/log
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-varlogaudit  3.0G   84M  3.0G   3% /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-home        1014M   33M  982M   4% /home
/dev/sda2                        1014M  358M  657M  36% /boot
/dev/sda1                         200M  9.9M  190M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs                             2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/user/0

and fdisk -l shows
[root@SERVER ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 4398.0 GB, 4398046511104 bytes, 8589934592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 56EB4CE6-541B-4A54-BE1C-5F2738DEDEA4


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      2508799      1G  Microsoft basic
 3      2508800     69617663     32G  Microsoft basic
 4     69617664   6264891391    2.9T  Linux LVM
 5   6264891392   6405408767     67G  Linux LVM
 6   6405408768   6442438655   17.7G  Linux swap
 7   6442438656   6442450910      6M  Linux filesyste

Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-root: 13.4 GB, 13421772800 bytes, 26214400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-storetmp: 16.1 GB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-tmp: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes, 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-home: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-opt: 13.4 GB, 13421772800 bytes, 26214400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-varlogaudit: 3221 MB, 3221225472 bytes, 6291456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-varlog: 16.1 GB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rootrhel-var: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes, 10485760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/storerhel-store: 3172.0 GB, 3171980148736 bytes, 6195273728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

This is what I see using parted and then print free
[root@SERVER ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4398GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
        17.4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Free Space
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16           EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   1285MB  1074MB  xfs
 3      1285MB  35.6GB  34.4GB  xfs
 4      35.6GB  3208GB  3172GB                                        lvm
 5      3208GB  3280GB  71.9GB                                        lvm
 6      3280GB  3299GB  19.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 7      3299GB  3299GB  6275kB
        3299GB  4398GB  1100GB  Free Space

(parted)

So 1TB is unallocated but I cannot find where is it to resize the partition
I tried using resize2fs, xfs_growfs, fdisk, parted but nothing happens
Any possible solution?
Thanks

You show two partitions after the LVM volumes. And last partition ends at 6442450910, but drive ends at 8589934592, so are sectors after partition 7 unallocated. Normally with LVM the entire drive, except ESP & usually /boot are inside the LVM.

Added more information on the post, tried this commands but is not allocating the free space
[root@SERVER ~]# lvextend -L +1050G /dev/mapper/storerhel-store
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[19122236]) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 25753: -bash
Insufficient free space: 268800 extents needed, but only 0 available
[root@SERVER ~]# lvextend /dev/mapper/storerhel-store -l+100%FREE
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[19241931]) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 25753: -bash
New size (756259 extents) matches existing size (756259 extents).

I so not know LVM. I think there are ways to add space into volume or create another volume. But you may just want to move 6 & 7 to end of drive and add space into the LVM. Not sure how to do that. Recommends swap be inside LVM. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459660&p=14027975#post14027975 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444855&p=13963156#post13963156

It is apparent that it is a RHEL server, but I recommend to add the info about the operating system version, since the LVM features and capacities may be different from one distribution to another and from one version to another.

There's still some guesswork here, but ...
It looks as if partition 7, the 6 MB file-system is unused. If that is correct, I'd delete it and create a new partition. Ideally you'd move the existing partitions 5 & 6 to the end of the disk so you could pvresize the current store, but I don't have a walk-through for command-line for you.
If you were able to use a rescue-cd and could afford down-time on the server you could boot off the rescue-cd and use gparted, a graphical frontend to parted, to move them (the command line tool dropped support for moving a while ago).
If downtime is not an option the simplest way is to create a new partition in the free space, and add that to the existing volume-group. Let's assume you deleted the tiny #7, and recreated it w/ 1TB. (If it is in use, create a new partition #8 and use that in the example below).
vgextend storerhel-store /dev/sda7

A vgdisplay should now show the volume group to have 1TB in available extents  (Free PE). After that you can
lvextend -r -l +<Available Size> /dev/mapper/storerhel-store

